# Radial mapping voronoi texture not working

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E0JyyWeptSA

this is his output:

[image: Theirs]

this is mine:
[image: Mine]

He only ever shows bits of his node editor at a time so I couldn't get a full pic of his. His version is older than mine (2.8 vs. 4.0) so some nodes are different, and my output is in no way the same.

I have the Voronoi texture but for some reason the radial gradient doesn't apply after the Voronoi. Like. It won't make the “spiral” I guess. I just want to know how to replicate his effect with my version.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Make sure to use the Color output from the ColorRamp (not the alpha).

Comment: @chistopher bennet TYSM!!! it's been driving me crazy for days ToT